# Python: Lists vs. calculations

Tags: python

I am new to programming, started with Python 2 months ago. Writing the obligatory post "hello world" program: Craps.

I included "odds bets" (AKA "behind" bets), which is a true-odds payout for rolling a number (4,5,6,8,9,10) before a 7. Payouts are: 2/1 for 4 & 10; 3/2 for 5 & 9; and 6/5 for 6 & 7.

I wrote a nifty formula for just this purpose:

```
 payout = (int(bet_amount*(36/(36-(abs(roll-7)*6)))))
```

My question: Did I waste my time? Would just putting the payouts in a list be more CPU efficient? Is there a general rule of thumb for lists vs formulas?

Thanks.

Comment: Lists sit in memory and occupy space. If you are worried about such a small matter, though, you are just micro-optimizing, and *that* is wasting time

Comment: Depending on how long it took you to come up with that formula I would say: Did you waste your time? Possibly. Is the formula approach "cleaner". Yes (Opinion). Does the formula give you a better runtime? Can't really answer that on this small scale. Does the formula use less memory? Yes. Is memory a concern for this specific problem? No. Could memory be a concern if you had a **lot** more numbers? Yes.